# How to handle data with names in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am about to experiment with clustering algorithms to cluster file attributes (e.g. access time).

Does scikit support clustering of named data, i.e., how can I retrieve the file names after the clustering algorithm run?

Is there a way to store metadata with the training data, e.g., the file names? This metadata should survive feature scaling, introduction of artificial features, etc.

Comment: Why not prepare both: 1. a list of your file names, 2. arrays (and matrices) of the corresponding features. Following the clustering (on 2.), you can use the indices to extract the names (from 1.)

Comment: I think the most basic way is just to keep track of the mapping between row indices and file names yourself. Essentially, you'd just store an array of file names, and their indices would be what sklearn sees; after clustering, you can get back the file names by indexing into this array. Still curious if anybody knows a more direct solution within sklearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to attach names or properties to rows in scikit-learn. This will change soon (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4497). But for now, it is really easy to keep track of this yourself. The order of the data points is the same as the order of the cluster labels you get out, so the first cluster label corresponds to the first file name etc